# Sufficient condition for continuity of function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

For a function of two variables to be continous, a sufficient condition is said to be that one of the partial derivatives exists and is bounded near the required point and the other partial derivative just exists at that point

I cant understand how the bounded partial derivative helps in the proof.Please explain this to me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put down the name of the book from where you got to know about this condition? I only read Thomas' Calculus, but there's no such contidtion about the continuity of function of two variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $p=(x_0,y_0)$ be the required point. For $(x,y)$ near $p$ with $y \ne y_0$ we have

$f(x,y)-f(p)=f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)+f(x_0,y)-f(p)$.

By the mean value theorem there is $t_x$ between $x $ and $x_0$ such that

$f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)=f_x(t_x,y)(x-x_0)$, hence

$f(x,y)-f(p)=f_x(t_x,y)(x-x_0)+\frac{f(x_0,y)-f(p)}{y-y_0}(y-y_0) $.

Since $f_x$ is bounded near $p$ we have $f_x(t_x,y)(x-x_0) \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to p$.

Furthermore $\frac{f(x_0,y)-f(p)}{y-y_0}(y-y_0) \to f_y(p) \cdot 0$ as $(x,y) \to p$.

Conclusion: $f(x,y)-f(p) \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to p$.

Comment: thanks now i get it

Comment: Is the converse true? I think not but I am unable to think of an example. That is, give an example of a 2-variable real valued function f such that f is continuous at (a,b); fxand fy exist in a nbd of (a,b); but neither fx nor fy are bounded in any nbd of (a,b).